# How is the built in C# linkedlist library so much quicker than a simple implementation?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have created a barebones linkedlist with the following node type that gets chained up:

```
class Node
{
     string SomeDataBecauseWhyNot;
     Node Next;
     Node Previous;
}
```

While iterating over the nodes I delete some occasionally like so:

```
void RemoveNode(Node n)
{
     n.Next.Previous = n.Previous
     n.Previous.Next = n.Next
}
```

This solution is about 3x slower than the C# LinkedList.Remove function.

I can't imagine why and would really love to know what the difference is in the internal C# implementation that makes it so much quicker?

Comment: Viewing the source reveals that they're doing what you are doing, plus a lot more. Perhaps your test was invalid?  You should probably [edit] and provide details of how you tested the performance of the two.

Comment: "_.. this method is an O(n)._" From [**MSDN - LinkedList<T>.Remove Method (T)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k87xw3hb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [Looks like they use the same method, only with more validation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,8144d5953ed28f53) (that's the link to the source). Try running your test application in `Release` mode.

Comment: You can see here the official source for the dotnet framework's list here : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,baf7f8812f420a83

Comment: oh perhaps the cause of the issue is that I am running in debug, the linkedlist class it's using may be linking to a release DLL perhaps...

Comment: As you are interested in fast performance make sure to also include the array-based `List<T>` implementation. Depending on your use of the collection, chances are high that it may be significantly faster than you think.

Comment: @FirstStep: “.. this method is an O(n).” -- That does not mean it can't be slower by a constant factor of 3 (as claimed by the OP), in fact the big O notation only is a measure of how an algorithm responds to changes in the input size, not a measure for the runtime.

Comment: @soshiki yes, you where comparing release compiled code to debug compiled code. You need to build in release mode (and do your timings in release mode) to have a valid real world comparison.